# What's the best way to rescue this beech?

Tags: trees, tree-care

My super bright son did this to the beautiful 100-year-old beech in our backyard.

Is there anything that can be done to save the tree?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Yes, do nothing.  Trees compartmentalize wounds so the bark will slowly grow together to seal off the area.  Do not put anything on the wound as that has been shown to make it worse.

Do observe the wound on a yearly basis to see if any other issues arise.